# Pointing a domain to securely connect to an ec2 instance running a python app

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, https, port

Say I have an AWS ec2 instance that is running a python application on a certain port say 8000. Also imagine I have a domain name say www.abcd.com that I own. What does it take to make my website use https and securely redirect to the app on my ec2 that is listening on port 8000? Is this even possible to do or do I need something like nginx in between?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you will need to ensure that your EC2 is in a public subnet with a public IP, it will also need its security group open on whatever port you are hitting it on (8000). At this point you should be able to hit your application on public ip:port.

Now if you want to do the above while using a domain you will want to use AWS's [Route 53 service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/Welcome.html). From this you can create a DNS routing using your domain. You will want to create a route from: application.example.com to your instances public ip. After doing so you should be able to visit: application.example.com and hit your application. [In doing the following it is possible now to make your EC2 instance private](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/public-load-balancer-private-ec2/).

Now if you wish to include HTTPS ontop of this, the best way would be to [create a public load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-getting-started.html) with a certificate attached, this would accept HTTPS traffic from your user, then forward that traffic over HTTP to your EC2 on a selected port (8000).
After doing this you will want to change your Route53 entry to point to your load balancer instead of directly at your EC2.

Comment: I am unable to get the thing to work end to end. In the load balancer I see the following section where it asks to set:
"Load Balancer Protocol, Load Balancer Port, Instance Protocol, Instance Port ,Cipher, SSL Certificate"
Is the LB protocol/port to be set to https/443 and instance protocol set to http/8000 since my application runs on port 8000 on an ec2? I am also setting the SSL certificate to what I got from the route 53 service.

Comment: @user2399453 The protocol you wish to use is HTTPS (443). This is what the load balancer recieves public traffic on. You must then configure the port at which the load balancer forwards that request to when it hits your EC2. If you are running through the AWS console this will be step '4. Configure Routing'. You will want to select HTTP and a port (8000) that you want the load balancer to communicate to your EC2 on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is totally possible.

**Here is step wise procedure to do it :-**

- you need to create `hosted zone` on [Route-53](https://console.aws.amazon.com/route53/home?#hosted-zones:) services of amazon
- Then it use `ns` to connect with your `domain` ( wherever you have registered)
- Then you need to connect your `ec2` instance `ip` with your hosted zone
- Now you can access your `ec2` instances using this domain, but it will be not `https`
- For `https`, you need `certificate`, which you can avail from `aws` [certificate-manager](https://console.aws.amazon.com/acm/home)
- After obtaining the `certificate`, Follow the steps from this blog [How to set up HTTPS for your domain on AWS](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-set-up-https-for-your-domain-on-aws-8f771686603d).

  **NOTE:-** This is just uber point, follow it and look for more insight to how you exactly do it in your case. I followed this step while deploying using `elastic-beanstalk`.

Comment: "After obtaining the certificate, connect it with your domain after which you can access the website using https." - This isn't clear at all for someone who appears to be new to DNS and HTTPS. Should at least point the user in the right direction to use CDN/ELB/ALB/Apache/Nginx